# How to save and restore each UISwitch states after UIViewController was dismissed

Tags: ios, objective-c

**EDIT:** I still need an answer!

I have got 2 UIViewControllers (let's call them **ParentVC** and **SecondVC**).

There are 11 UISwitch elements on SecondVC and 1 button to send states for each UISwitch from SecondVC to ParentVC.

In parentVC i need an NSArray which would contain Keys of NSDictionary (was described in IBAction).
I have the IBAction:

```
NSDictionary *resultDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               [NSNumber numberWithBool: [_cafeSwitch isOn]], @"Cafe",
                               .....
                               [NSNumber numberWithBool: [_bowlingSwitch isOn]], @"BowlingClub",
                               nil];
    NSMutableArray *resultArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *key in resultDic) {
        NSNumber *value = [resultDic valueForKey:key];
        if ([value compare:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]] == NSOrderedSame)
            [resultArray addObject:key];
    }
    [_delegate sendSelectedPlaceTypeArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:resultArray]];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{}];
```

The method `sendSelectedPlaceTypeArray` is the delegate method to receive this NSArray in ParentVC.
All switchers are selected by default state. 
In ParentVC i have implementation of delegate method:

```
- (void)sendSelectedPlaceTypeArray:(NSArray *)placeTypeArray {
    filteredPlaceTypeArray_ = placeTypeArray;
}
```

By default filteredPlaceTypeArray_ contains all 11 place types.

```
filteredPlaceTypeArray_ = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Cafe", ... ,@"BowlingClub", nil];
```

The method which presents SecondVC is:

```
- (IBAction)showPlaceTypeFilter:(id)sender {
    UIStoryboard *iPhoneStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    PlaceTypeFilterViewController *destViewController = [iPhoneStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlaceTypeFilterViewController"];
    destViewController.delegate = self;
    destViewController.currentFilteredPlaceTypesArray = filteredPlaceTypeArray_;
    [self presentViewController:destViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

**I have got a number of questions:**

1. Is it good solution to work with filters?
2. How to save and restore UISwitch elements values if SecondVC has been called twice or more and for example 2 of 11 UISwitch elements were changed? What is the best solution for this? Because when SecondVC appears all UISwitch elements were selected.

I hope my question is correct, thanks, Artem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As i understod from you, here is the way to get all objects from the view:

```
for (UISwitch *mySwitch in [self.view subviews]) {
    if ([mySwitch isKindOfClass:[UISwitch class]]) {
        NSLog(@"State == %@",[mySwitch description]);
        //Do what ever you want to do with your switches 
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: this answer is related to the original question before it was edited.

> How to set states for each UISWitch programmatically

Comment: I have got the correct state for each of my USSwitch elements. The question is: how to save and restore this values if SecondVC has been called twice or more and for example 2 of 11 UISwitch elements were changed.

Comment: Then your question is asked wrongly!! read your question header !!